# Laravel 5 restrict access to pages using middleware

Tags: laravel-5, roles, middleware

I am working on a laravel project and i need to restrict access to some pages such that only authenticated users can view that page.

To do this, created a middleware: `php artisan make:middleware OnlyRegisteredUser`
and registered it in the `$routemiddleware` inside `App\Http\kernel.php` as 
`'onlyregistereduser' => \App\Http\Middleware\OnlyRegisteredUser::class,`

and this is the class. it redirects user to `auth/login` if not logged in

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $right=null)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    if ($user && $user->onlyregistereduser()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('auth/login');
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('admin/poem', ['middleware' => 'onlyregistereduser:admin', 'uses'=>'PoemsController@poem']);
```

`admin` is a parameter passed to my middleware. It is taken from my user model which has an `enum' column as follows:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         //...
        $table->enum('rights', ['admin', 'guest'])->nullable();
         // ...
    });
}
```

Now to restrict access to **some** of my controller methods, e.g create, i added a constructor to my `PoemsController` as shown:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('onlyregistereduser');
}
```

My problem now is that this caused every single route to the `PoemsController` to redirect me to the login page. And again after login in, it doesn't take me to the page i intended to visit. it takes me instead to the home page. What i want is to restrict access to only some of the controller methods and not all of them and to be able to redirect to the intended page after user login.
I hope you understand my problem. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the middleware from constructor, you don't have to add middleware to both route and costructor. That should solve your ". What i want is to restrict access to only some of the controller methods and not all of them" issue.

For othe issue modify your middleware like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $right=null)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    if ($user && $user->onlyregistereduser()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    $request_url = $request->path();
    session()->put('login_refferrer', $request_url);
    return redirect('auth/login');
}
```

and before redirect user after login

```
 if(session()->has('login_refferrer')){
  $url = session()->pull('login_refferrer');
  return redirect($url);
}
```